# Locus of focus of variable parabola

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

> A variable parabola is drawn to pass through A & B, the ends of a
>   diameter of a given circle with centre at the origin and radius c & to
>   have as directrix a tangent to a concentric circle of radius 'a' (a>c) ; the axes being AB & a perpendicular diameter, prove that the locus of the focus of the parabola is the standard ellipse
>   $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$ where $b^2= a^2– c^2$.

**Doubt:**

I am not being able to frame to equation of the variable parabola. I feel that any parabola can have a double ordinate whose length is equal to $2c$, which can pass through the ends of diameter of the smaller circle. However, one catch is that the directrix must be a tangent to the bigger circle. But how to write the equation of such a variable parabola, whose locus of focus I need to find ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need to know the equation of the parabola.

We may assume that $A(c,0),B(-c,0)$.

Let $F(X,Y)$ be the coordinates of the focus of the parabola.

The equation of the directrix is given by $mx+ny=a^2$ where $P(m,n)$ is the tangent point such that $m^2+n^2=a^2$.

Now, by the definition of the parabola, the distance from the focus to $(\pm c,0)$ is equal to the distance from $(\pm c,0)$ to the directrix.

So, we get
$$\sqrt{(X-c)^2+(Y-0)^2}=\frac{|mc+n\cdot 0-a^2|}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}},$$
i.e.
$$a^2(X-c)^2+a^2Y^2=m^2c^2-2mca^2+a^4\tag1$$
Also,
$$\sqrt{(X+c)^2+(Y-0)^2}=\frac{|m(-c)+n\cdot 0-a^2|}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}},$$
i.e.
$$a^2(X+c)^2+a^2Y^2=m^2c^2+2mca^2+a^4\tag2$$

From $(1)-(2)$,
$$a^2(-4cX)=-4mca^2\implies X=m$$
From $(1)+(2)$,
$$a^2X^2+a^2c^2+a^2Y^2=m^2c^2+a^4\implies a^2X^2+a^2c^2+a^2Y^2=X^2c^2+a^4$$
which can be written as
$$\frac{X^2}{a^2}+\frac{Y^2}{a^2-c^2}=1$$

Comment: Why did you assume that A and B lie on the x-axis ?

Comment: @S007: That's a good point. My understanding was that "the axes being AB & a perpendicular  diameter" implies that A and B are on the x-axis, but, as you suggest, my understanding might be wrong. However, taking $A(c\cos\theta,c\sin\theta),B(-c\cos\theta,-c\sin\theta)$ gives me $\frac{X^2}{a^2}+\frac{Y^2}{a^2-c^2\cos^2\theta}=1$. So, anyway, from the given answer, I think that the question does imply that A and B are on the x-axis. (but I now agree that the expression is unclear.)

Comment: @S007: In other words, if A and B are not on the x-axis, we cannot get the given answer. (the ellipse in the given answer is not rotated)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. One more thing. Can we intuitively say that (X,Y)'s locus will be an ellipse without calculation ?

Comment: @S007: Finally, I got it. Yes, we can intuitively say so. All we need to show is that $FA+FB=\text{(constant)}$, i.e. $\text{(the distance from $A$ to the directrix)}+\text{(the distance from $B$ to the directrix)}=\text{(constant)}$. This is obvious. (Let $S,T,U$ be a point on the directrix $L$ such that $AS\perp L, OT\perp L, BU\perp L$ respectively. Since $OA=OB$, we have $AS+BU=2OT=2a$.)

Comment: What does $O$ stand for in $OA=OB$ ?

Comment: @S007: It stands for the origin.